# How to reduce an array of objects by key and sum its values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I am trying to turn this:

```
var crates = [{category: "fruits", type: "apple", color: "green", number: 1}, 
             {category: "fruits", type: "apple", color: "red", number: 1},
             {category: "fruits", type: "banana", color: "yellow", number: 1}, 
             {category: "vegetables", type: "onion", color: "white", number: 1}]
```

into this:

```
var stand = [{category: "fruits", type: "apple", sum: 2}, 
             {category: "fruits", type: "banana", sum: 1}, 
             {category: "vegetables", type: "onion", sum: 1}]
```

using lodash/fp. So far I have tried a lot, this is the closest I managed to get:

```
var stand = flow(
      groupBy('type'),
      map((objs, key) => ({
          'category': key,
          'type': key,
          'sum': _.sumBy(objs, 'number') }))
    )(crates);
```

which results in:

```
[{category: undefined, type: undefined, sum: 2},
{category: undefined, type: undefined, sum: 1}
{category: undefined, type: undefined, sum: 1}]
```

So obviuously I don't get how to pass reference to the "category" and "type" values to the map function.

I'm new into lodash/fp and struggling with the whole fp concept, so I would be happy for anything that might point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lodash-fp methods have a fixed arity of 1 (callback receives 1 argument) to support auto-currying. This means that the `map`'s callback doesn't get the key. You can get the `type`, and the `category` from the 1st object in the group.

To allow currying the `sumBy()` parameters are switched, so the `objs` should be the 2nd param:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, map, sumBy } = _;

const crates = [{"category":"fruits","type":"apple","color":"green","number":1},{"category":"fruits","type":"apple","color":"red","number":1},{"category":"fruits","type":"banana","color":"yellow","number":1},{"category":"vegetables","type":"onion","color":"white","number":1}];

const result = flow(
  groupBy('type'),
  map((objs) => ({
    'category': objs[0].category,
    'type': objs[0].type,
    'sum': sumBy('number', objs)
  }))
)(crates);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-fp/0.10.4/lodash-fp.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I was hoping for! Thank you for the solution and the explanation. I definitely need to learn more about this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with Array.reduce, and Array.findIndex.

```js
var crates = [{ category: "fruits", type: "apple", color: "green", number: 1 },
{ category: "fruits", type: "apple", color: "red", number: 1 },
{ category: "fruits", type: "banana", color: "yellow", number: 1 },
{ category: "vegetables", type: "onion", color: "white", number: 1 }]


console.log(
    crates.reduce(
        (crates, item) => {
            const index = crates.findIndex(i => {
                return i.type == item.type && i.category == item.category
                }
            )
            if (index > -1) crates[index].sum += item.number
            else { crates.push({ type: item.type, category: item.category, sum: item.number }) }
            return crates;
        }, [])
);
```

While it's a little more verbose than lodash, learning standard array methods to solve a problem will make you less dependent on third party libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the resulting array has two separate objects for apple, I would need one object with a "sum" value of 2, can you explain how to achieve this with your method?

Comment: Yes, corrected, a return statement was missing in findIndex callback

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow beginner, I'm with @mpm: consider it a practice opportunity to write your own versions of lodash utilities. It's a MASSIVE library, and chances are you won't be using enough of it to justify adding it to your dependencies in package.json. Here's yet another approach splitting into two steps, first breaking your input array down into an object (with sums of fruit types) then pushing new objects into an output array:

```js
const standMaker = (crates) => {
  var fruits = {};
  for (let fruit of crates) {
    if (!fruits[fruit.type]) {
      fruits[fruit.type] = {};
      fruits[fruit.type].sum = 1;
      fruits[fruit.type].category = fruit.category;
    } else if (fruits[fruit.type]) {
      fruits[fruit.type].sum += 1;
    }
  };
  var stand = [];
  for (let fruit in fruits) {
    stand.push({category: fruits[fruit].category, type: fruit, sum: fruits[fruit].sum});
  }
  console.log(stand);
}
```